# Grouping list of values from mvc model to html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have ran into a challenge working with an asp .net mvc project.

What I have is a recipe generator page that will display recipe names, ingredients, and instructions in a table using html.

I pull recipe information from my database and in my database each recipe has multiple ingredients that go with it.

The challenge for me is to get the recipe name, corresponding ingredients, and instructions all in one html table row. The problem I have been trying to work around is that it will display multiple rows for the same recipe because the ingredients are being listed multiple times so I tried to make it to where the model has a list of ingredients attached to it per recipe but it has not been working out very well.

I will show my code for the Model, View, and Controller I have now in hope that someone can possibly tweak my methods and point me in the right direction.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyPantry.Models
{
    public class Recipes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }
    }

}
```

View:

```
<h1 class="m-b-20" style="font-size: 4vw; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 37%; margin-right: 41.5%; border-style: solid">My Recipes</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        @model List<Recipes>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table- hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Ingredients</th>
                <th>Instructions</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var recipe in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@recipe.Name</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => recipe.IngredientName)</td>
                    <td>@recipe.Instructions</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
       public IActionResult RecipeList()
    {
        var ls = new List<Recipes>();

        SqlConnection connection = GetConnection();

        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("SELECT ingredients.name as IngName, recipes.name, recipes.instructions ");
                sb.Append("FROM recipes, recipe_ingredients, ingredients ");
                sb.Append("WHERE recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id and recipe_ingredients.Ingredient_id = ingredients.id;");
                String sql = sb.ToString();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            var recipe = new Recipes();
                            recipe.Name = rdr["name"].ToString();
                            recipe.Instructions = rdr["instructions"].ToString();
                            recipe.IngredientName.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["IngName"]));

                            ls.Add(recipe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return View(ls);

    }
```

Comment: You're going in the correct direction with your model. I would recommend creating models for your other tables as well, instead of having a List of strings in your model. Then, you should look into HTML rowspans and colspans if you're interested in merging cells. I would recommend you don't do this, though, and have a button on each row to click that would then show the details for that row.

Comment: Thank you, having a button for recipe information is a great idea and is probably better for the user and making the page less cluttered.

Comment: If you're able to use Entity Framework, you can generate a basic CRUD program using your Recipes model, and then modify it to be a fairly good table. This will automatically set up the details page for you. You could delete the Create, Delete, and Update functionality of the program. Otherwise, you'll be recreating the wheel here. If you can't use Entity Framework, I suggest you read some tutorials on developing CRUD interfaces to get an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Jack says, but you might also want to look into Joins with your SQL Scripts as well as using Distinct to avoid retrieving your multiples of Ingredient data. You could use a nested query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Update... I came up with a solution that works for my table.

Controller:

```
      public IActionResult RecipeList()
    {
        var ls = new List<Recipes>();

        SqlConnection connection = GetConnection();

        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct recipes.name, recipes.instructions from recipes;");
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    var recipe = new Recipes();
                    recipe.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["name"]);
                    recipe.IngredientName = RecipeIngredientsList(recipe.Name);
                    recipe.Instructions = Convert.ToString(dr["instructions"]);
                    ls.Add(recipe);
                }

            }
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return View(ls);

    }

    public List<string> RecipeIngredientsList(string Name)
    {
        List<string> ingredients = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection connection = GetConnection();

        try
        {
           using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ingredients.name " +
                                                "from ingredients, recipe_ingredients, recipes " +
                                                "where recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.recipe_id and recipe_ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.id and recipes.name = @Name;");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    ingredients.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["name"]) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return ingredients;

    }
```

View:

```
   <h1 class="m-b-20" style="font-size: 4vw; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 37%; margin-right: 38%; border-style: solid">My Recipes</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        @model List<Recipes>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Ingredients</th>
                <th>Instructions</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var recipe in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@recipe.Name</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => recipe.IngredientName)</td>
                <td>@recipe.Instructions</td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Model:

```
namespace MyPantry.Models
{
    public class Recipes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZX1B.jpg)